# Display alert before delete sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL server 2008 and we do have access to prod database . 
Currently while executing queries particularly DDL I always check which server it's pointing to but
sometimes I may go careless and things may go wrong, so how to automate that?

Is't possible to display the alert before performing delete or update operation in SQL server management studio ?

Or avoid DDL execution when connected to prod server?

Example : when you send mail without subject in outlook it will alert you similar type of setting

Comment: You could remove your permissions so if you accidentally *go careless* it won't allow it :).  There are also tools like [SSMS Tools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) which will allow you to give a colored bar at the top of the query window, you could make the bar red if you're connected to Production and green if you're connected to dev/qa/etc... I believe this is also possible within SSMS itself, but not positive.

Comment: Why are you messing around with the prod DB? Also, for displaying a warning of some sort, you really should be utilizing the front end, which I see no mention of. Is this a web app? winforms? That's where I think most people would have an 'alert' display to the user. As for SQL Server specific, I'm not sure.

Comment: Its not from application while working with SSMS. Moreover I am speaking about accidental deletion while working with SSMS . Removing the permission won't allow me to execute the query at anytime even its needed. What I need is confirmation before doing DDL or at least while delete. Speaking about third party tools. Don't we have this type of cool feature in SSMS itself?

Comment: The best practice is that you use minimum permission required for the job. You may use read-only account for everyday job but when you need special permission then you need to logon to another special account. Even with tools you will go careless one day or another.

Answer (score 4):

I have developed SSMSBoost add-in for SSMS and there is a feature there allowing to declare some database as "Important". In this case you will see additional warning when you switch to this database. In next releases we plan to add some further restrictions, like "no DML statements" or "no DML statements without WHERE"

Feature description can be found here:
http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-preferred-connections

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply i tried that and it's cool but it would be very useful if alert is coming for "DML Statement" as you said. Currently it was displayed always

Comment: I am going to add additional "warning" functionality for DML statements on "important" servers, as well as warnings for "DML without WHERE clause". I have already the technology for that and have the feature in to-do list. Stay tuned !